# Можно ли прошить планшет на android прошивкой другого планшета?

Tags: android, прошивка

Есть планшет DEX IP977(проц rockchip 3188), на него нашел одну единственную прошивку родную и там стоит андроид 4.2.2, никакие проги толком он не поддерживает, в плей маркете даже ютуб не доступен. В идеале хочу его прошить хотя бы до версии 5.1, и вот вопрос а вообще возможно ли это? Где искать прошивки? Нужно ли учитывать разрешение экрана планшета при этом, или там все как то автоматически подгоняется? Ну и вообще встанет ли какая то чужая прошивка или он превратится в кирпич и я вообще не смогу его потом восстановить?

Comment: Ищите инструкции на https://4pda.to или на https://www.xda-developers.com, попробуйте спросить здесь: https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=513262

Comment: В данный момент ваш вопрос слишком обширный и в нем содержится сразу несколько вопросов. Это не соответствует правилам Stack Overflow. Сфокусируйте ваш вопрос на одной проблеме, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначный конкретный ответ. Прочитайте, [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) и [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).